# Using an external font in html source

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm looking at this webpage:

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/

In the first and second method, in order to use the font you will need to add a line of code like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

**Question:** Does the entire content of the folder get downloaded when I add this line to my source code? The entire content of that folder is about 1MB however it really wouldn't make sense for the entire folder to get downloaded every time I just want to use a single icon.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content does not get downloaded automatically, you have to download it yourself and reference it in your Project. Alternatively you can use the CDN `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`